# Update RecyclerView from DialogFragment and main Activity

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, dialogfragment

What's the best pattern to do it. I made some workaround but I feel this is a bad pattern.

My scenario.

I've got main Activity

**MainActivity.java**

In this activity I'm loading Fragment with RecyclerView.

**ListFragment.java**

I've got also **DialogFragment** and **ItemAdapter**

From the adapter I'm showing the DialogFragment

**Full adapter code**

```
public class TypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CostTypeAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "TypeAdapter";
    private List<CostType> mCostsType;
    private Context mContext;

public CostTypeAdapter(Context context, List<CostType> coststype) {
    mContext = context;
    mCostsType = coststype;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view.
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.costtype_row, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

// BEGIN_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnBindViewHolder)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");
    String Name = mCostsType.get(position).getName();
    viewHolder.tvName.setText(Name);

    //mView click
    viewHolder.cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Dialog here
            FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(mContext);
            FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

            CostType costType = new CostType();
            costType.setTypeID(mCostsType.get(position).getTypeID());
            costType.setName(mType.get(position).getName());
            costType.setPriority(0);
            CostsTypeDialogFragment alertDialog = CostsTypeDialogFragment.newInstance(costType);
            alertDialog.show(fm, "cost_type");

        }
    });


}
// END_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnCreateViewHolder)

public void refreshList() {
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("refreshList");

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mType.size();
}

/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
 */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView tvName;
    private final CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");

            }
        });
        tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }

}



}
```

**DialogFragment.java**
I have listener for this dialog to communicate with MainActivity

```
    onDialogCloseListener mListener;
    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface onDialogCloseListener {
        public void onDialogClose();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (onDialogCloseListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnDialogClose listener");
        }
    }
    private List<MyType> mType;

    ...
```

onClick from the dialog:

```
mListener.onDialogClose();
```

This dialog has some button. One of the is for example to modify/delete item on the recycle list. In this dialog I have interface onDialogCloseListener. I'm using in on my MainActivity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements DialogFragment.onDialogCloseListener {

    ... 
    @Override
    public void onDialogClose() {

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        //not working
        mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I can use the mRecyclerView from the Activity this way. I can for example make it invisible. But the notifyDataSetChanged is not working.

My workaround is to create new adapter - new sql query, new list of objects and set it again for RecyclerView. But this is probably not a good way. Because I can't for example keep scroll position.

But how to make a connection with the adapter? I want to be able to add animation for example for deleting item.

**Edit:**

Running

```
mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(0);
```

in the onDialogClose works great. The list is refreshed. But when I want to do the same with

```
mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or

```
mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(0);
```

The list is not refreshing.

Comment: do you just need to notify the data set changed on the adapter?

Comment: @Onheiron it would be the easiest way but I read that it's not so easy with RecyclerView. If there is on option to use only notifyDataSetChanged so yes. But I need to be able to get item from the adapter. For example while deleting show the animation, keep the scroll position.

Comment: could you post your full Adapter code?

Comment: Another thing. This is working:
mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(0) 

Removing works great. I can see the animation. So the problem is to achieve something similar for editing record.

For example:
mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(16)

don't refresh the list.

Answer (score 5):

**Advice 1**: don't show dialog inside adapter class, make your `onClick` trigger your own listener inside `Activity` e.g. `onItemClicked(CostType costType)`

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter .. {

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(CostType costType);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    // setter and getter for OnitemClickListener

    // inside onBindViewHolder
    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        CostType costType = new CostType();
        costType.setTypeID(mCostsType.get(position).getTypeID());
        costType.setName(mType.get(position).getName());
        costType.setPriority(0);
        mListener.onItemClicked(costType);
      }

}

class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // inside onCreate
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ...);

}
```

**Advice 2**: if you need to deliver result from Fragment B to Fragment A, you don't need to use activity, instead use `setTargetFragment` / `getTargetFragment` methods.

```
// inside MyListFragment
MyDialogFragment frag = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
frag.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
// commit transaction

// inside MyDialogFragment to trigger listener, make sure MyDialogFragment
// implement OnDialogCloseListener interface
((MyListFragment)getTargetFragment()).onDialogClose();
```

Comment: Thanks. That's why I was asking for good pattern. So I should move my onClick to the MainActivity (not the fragment activity). But how to do that. The same way I made with DialogFragment listener?

Comment: You've got +1 from me. But this is probably not resolving my issue with updating the recyclerview list. Where I should add notifyDataSetChanged(). In the MyActivity it's not working. Probably moving this code here won't change that but I'll try.

Comment: @adek try to do the following: 1) Make sure `onDialogClose` method is called. 2) After calling `notifyDataSetChanged` method `onBindViewHolder` is called? 3) When creating your adapter, keep reference to adapter as class variable in activity. E.g. replace `mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()` to `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: OK but the mAdapter is in FragmentList. OnDialog called is in the MyActivity class. OnAttach is connected to the main activity. But from the main activity I'm able to get mRecyclerView reference - for example mRecyclerView visibility change works. So getAdapter() should work in my opinion.

Comment: @adek you are right, your code should work anyway. I have added another Advice 2.

Comment: Are sure the pattern with OnItemClickListener is right. I have no idea how to make it work. I can't achieve adapter.setOnItemClickListener work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81949/discussion-between-dmytro-danylyk-and-adek).